# Inkscape selection borders are too big when using the rectangle tool

Tags: inkscape

today I encountered a problem that's never occurred before. The selection borders on my rectangles are very large. It stays like that even if I convert the object to path. It's messing up exporting sizes, so any help is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to duplicate your image by creating a rectangle with black fill, white stroke of excessive width. I suspect you'll need to reduce your stroke width in order to reduce the bounding box to the size you require.

Comment: That's it, thanks a bunch. I didn't notice that.